# how to make grid in bootstrap album class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have following bootstrap 4 code with album class

```
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
  <div class="container ">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

but now I need make same 3 grid system in the `<div class="album py-5 bg-light">` class, but when I make   `<div class="col-md-4">` in the album tag without `container` it is not working. then how could I manage this as well?

Comment: Please clarify the problem/question. The additional `col-md-4` would be added to the `row` since columns must be the immediate children of `row` for the grid to work.

Comment: @Zim I need add same hight and width div boxes in to the `<div class="album py-5 bg-light">`